# How to get the second word from Java Scanner input?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

Maybe it just requires a method of `String` but I really need to get the value of the second word from `Scanner` input received like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String a;
a = in.nextLine();
```

Comment: Use `a.split("\\s+");`?

Comment: If you are running your code from the command line, you should consider using the `args` variable which is passed to `main()` rather than reading from standard input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're defining "word" as the part split off by a space, and there are exactly two words entered:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String a;
a = in.nextLine();
String secondWord = a.substring(a.indexOf(" "));
```

If there may be more, use split:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String a;
a = in.nextLine();
String secondWord = a.split("\\s+")[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

like this `a.split(" ")` the result will be array of size 2, where second element will be results.txt

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scanner.next()`. A unit test case to demonstrate:

```
@Test
public void testSecondWordSingleLine() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("hello hi there");
    scanner.next();
    assertEquals("hi", scanner.next());
}
```

It works also if the second word is on a new line, for example:

```
@Test
public void testSecondWordMultiLine() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("hello\nhi there");
    scanner.next();
    assertEquals("hi", scanner.next());
}

@Test
public void testSecondWordMultiLineWithNextLineFirst() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("hello\nhi there");
    scanner.nextLine();
    assertEquals("hi", scanner.next());
}
```